# Why won't my minecraft horses breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My two horses just won't breed. I've tried golden apples, golden carrots and normal carrots. I've tried with many horses but it doesn't work!! Am I doing something wrong? They're both tamed as well.

Comment: I believe that taming them prevents breeding, but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should just have to right click two **tamed** horses with either golden carrots or golden apples. This should work as long as they haven't been bred within the last 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Horses have a taming cooldown of 5 minutes; if you have tamed them in last 5 minutes, you need to wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a breeding limit. Say you have a farm and breed sheep, chickens, cows, or pigs. You need to kill some of the animals you bred in order to breed the horses. I made this mistake when I was new to minecraft and wasted several golden carrots.

Answer (score 0):

Horses need to have enough space to breed! That fixed the issue for me. I had a pretty small enclosure for them and it just wasn’t working